# How can I set textbox to read only using a Telerik Radgrid UserControl

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid

I have a Telerik RadGrid using a User Control for edit an Insert.  Configured like this

```
 <MasterTableView AutoGenerateColumns="false" CommandItemDisplay="Top"
                        DataKeyNames="Form_UsageId" Font-Size="Medium"
                        NoMasterRecordsText="No Transfer Locker Records Added" InsertItemPageIndexAction="ShowItemOnCurrentPage"
                        CommandItemSettings-AddNewRecordText="Add New Transfer Locker Entry">
                        <Columns>
                            <telerik:GridEditCommandColumn ButtonType="ImageButton" UniqueName="EditCommandColumn"></telerik:GridEditCommandColumn>
                            <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="CaseNumber" HeaderText="Case Number" DataField="CaseNumber"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                            <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="ItemCount" HeaderText="# of Items" DataField="ItemCount"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                            <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="PersonFor" HeaderText="Person Intended For" DataField="PersonIntendedFor"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                            <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="PersonAdding" HeaderText="Person Putting In" DataField="PersonAdding"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                            <telerik:GridDateTimeColumn DataField="DateIn" HeaderText="Date Put In"
                                PickerType="DatePicker" EnableTimeIndependentFiltering="true" DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}">
                            </telerik:GridDateTimeColumn>
                            <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="TotalDays" HeaderText="# Days Open" DataField="TotalDays"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                        </Columns>
                        <EditFormSettings UserControlName="TransferLockerUserControl.ascx" EditFormType="WebUserControl" PopUpSettings-Modal="false">
                            <EditColumn UniqueName="EditCommandColumn1"></EditColumn>
                        </EditFormSettings>
                    </MasterTableView>
```

I am using a User Control for editing a record and I need to set some of the text boxes to read only.  This is what I have tried

```
if (e.Item.IsInEditMode && e.Item is GridEditableItem)
        {
            if (e.Item.ItemIndex == -1)
            {
                // insert
                GridEditableItem item = e.Item as GridEditableItem;

            }
            else
            {
                // edit
                GridEditableItem item = e.Item as GridEditableItem;
                (item["CaseNumber"].Controls[0] as TextBox).ReadOnly = true;
            }

        }
```

This fails and generates the error
[image]

Can someone help me fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the answer to this problem  I have posted the working code below.

```
if (e.Item.IsInEditMode && e.Item is GridEditableItem)
        {
            if (e.Item.ItemIndex == -1)
            {
                // insert
                GridEditableItem item = e.Item as GridEditableItem;

            }
            else
            {
                // edit
                GridEditableItem item = e.Item as GridEditableItem;
                UserControl userControl = (UserControl)e.Item.FindControl(GridEditFormItem.EditFormUserControlID);
                TextBox txt = (TextBox)userControl.FindControl("txtCaseNumber"); //access TextBox here
                txt.ReadOnly = true;
            }

        }
```